# How to change the title with UserScripts?

Tags: javascript, twitter, userscripts

i'm trying to change the title of twitter since they changed it to have X in it, but from all i can gather here on stack overflow and Github etc is the way to do that by using `document.title`, but when i tries to do that does it not work, it not only doesn't change the title, it doesn't even wanna get the title (made it output the title and new_title with `console.log` and nothing gets outputted)

```
var title = document.title;
if (title.endsWith("/ X")) {
  var new_title = title.slice(0, -3) + "/ Twitter";
  document.title = new_title;
}
```

here is the full code incase it may be the rest of the script that's the problem https://gist.github.com/biast12/04f66af3297b9395ec489f7eb16a9286 / https://gist.github.com/biast12/04f66af3297b9395ec489f7eb16a9286/raw/Replace-twitter-logo.user.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Twitter is a JS app, it dynamically changes the title as the user navigates. The title is also injected into the page at a time slightly after the initial page load. Currently, that means when you check `document.title`, it hasn't been set by the twitter applications client-side yet.

To get around this we need to capture:

1. When the title element is first added to the page.
2. All subsequent alterations to that title element.

It can be done with `MutationObserver`:

```
function fixTitle() {
  var title = document.title;

  if (title === "X") {
    document.title = "Twitter";
  }

  if (title.endsWith("/ X")) {
    var new_title = title.slice(0, -3) + "/ Twitter";
    document.title = new_title;
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    // Ignore changes to <head> apart from when <title> is added
    if (
      !mutations.some((mutation) =>
        [...mutation.addedNodes].some((node) => node.nodeName === "TITLE"),
      )
    )
      return;

    // Fix initially added title
    fixTitle();

    // Watch the new title element for any change now it exists
    new MutationObserver(function () {
      fixTitle();
    }).observe(document.querySelector("title"), {
      characterData: true,
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });
  }).observe(document.querySelector("head"), { childList: true });
});
```

I noticed there was still a flash of `X` on page load as it first puts the title in as `X` then it changes it to the format `[page] / X`. So I also added an extra condition to check for that.

We have a shared dedication on this matter . Feel free to use this in your public script.

[image]

Comment: Yes this works! thanks! now i understand why it didn't work, i may also rewrite the rest of the script to follow this code

Comment: anyway you maybe can contact me on another platform? would love to get some help on how to make the rest of the UserScript like this, especially because i'm having a few people saying there's an issue on firefox, my Twitter and Discord is @biast12